# How to handle common code that's being used in multiple applications

Tags: svn, code-reuse, modularity

In our applications we have quite some code that is being used in multiple applications.  The code is shared using SVN externals (see question [Multiple apps with common code -- how to approach this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757382/multiple-apps-with-common-code-how-to-approach-this)).
To simplify deployment we create standalone executables (no DLL's).

The problem is that we are not only getting pieces of common code with simple functionality, but also pieces of code with functionality that relies on other common code.  E.g.:

- Module A contains common functionality A
- Module B contains common functionality B
- Module X contains common functionality X, but requires A and B.

In many cases it's not purely about some module that requires another module, but also "if you have module A and module B, then you need module X to link their functionality together".

Since we use an SVN external for every module of common code, we end up with a big set of externals.  For a lot of combinations of modules we have other modules:

- If you have modules A and B, you also need module X
- If you have modules B and C, you also need module Y
- If you have modules A and C, you also need module Z
- ...

Although SVN externals makes it quite clear, it is still very cumbersome to use:

- We regularly need to create new modules if we add functionality that depends on 2 (or more) other modules
- We regularly need to change the externals of all the applications if new modules are added
- SVN updates take longer and longer

Are there any good patterns or techniques that can be used to make this easier (or faster, ...)?  E.g.:

- Using #define and #ifdef to only include code that relies on module A if module A is really present (we used to do this 15 years ago but I'm not a fan of this approach)
- Recursive externals (does this exist?)
- Something with DLL's? (although this probably only makes the problem worse)
- ...

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Do the modules need source code or just build output?  Could you create build output of module-a-devel and stick it in Maven so you don't have to hit subversion for all the little externals updates?

Comment: It depends.  Often we only need the build output of these externals, so we could centrally build a library and distribute this one.  But the downside is that if you need to do some developments in your application which also means an extension to the common code, you need to do your developments in two different environments.  Therefore I still prefer to have the source code of the common modules in every application.  Thanks for the refererence to Maven; didn't know that.